# CSS code use to make sure that only 2 line sentence to display is not working for IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I have the following css code to make sure that the display sentence is not more then 2 line, if so it will replace the rest of the word to "..."

```
   .bell-notification-max-words-display{
      overflow: hidden;
      display: -webkit-box;
      -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
      -webkit-box-orient: vertical;  
    }
```

This working fine for chrome, safari and mozilla. However, it's not working for IE. When I inspect the element, error showing like below:

[image]

Does anyone know how can I make it work for IE?

Comment: Are you sure that this is working in mozilla? - As far as I know firefox won't  display an ellipsis here - just webkit based browsers (which also makes sense being that the property being used here is (the non-standard) -**webkit**-line-clamp`)

Answer (score 0):

Have you try all these?

```
display: -moz-box;
display: -webkit-box;
display: box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
```

Answer (score 0):

The [vendor prefix](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Vendor_Prefix) `-webkit` means that this is specific to the [webkit engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebKit) which IE does not use. That's why it doesn't work.

You can get the desired result with a bit of `line-height` tweaking. - Read more about [line-height](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/line-height) - and by also using `overflow: hidden;`

Setting  [overflow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/overflow) to hidden means the content will be trimmed if it exceeds the dimensions of the div:

**Working example:**

```css
.parent {
  font-size:16px;
  height: 36px; /* 2x "font-size" +4px clearing */
  line-height: 36px; /* should match your parent div height */
  width: 90%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.child {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: normal; /* reset line height here it here */
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, cu ancillae expetendis ius, pro reque laudem facilisis in, dicta euismod qui eu. No pri graecis similique, ei vim nobis veritus argumentum, platonem torquatos vituperata eum eu. Mel purto eros legendos id, saepe laudem at qui,
    te eum semper interesset. Has id admodum deleniti, eu sumo iisque noluisse ius, vix facer partiendo temporibus ut. In civibus consetetur cum, quo atqui omnium periculis ne. Vim nullam nemore ut.
  </div>
</div>
```

There also another method in which you use a [reset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/all) html [textarea element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea).

**Working example:**

```css
textarea {
  all: unset;
  width: 100%
}

.sample {
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 80%;
  overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<textarea class="sample" rows="2">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, cu ancillae expetendis ius, pro reque laudem facilisis in, dicta euismod qui eu. No pri graecis similique, ei vim nobis veritus argumentum, platonem torquatos vituperata eum eu. Mel purto eros legendos id, saepe laudem at qui,
    te eum semper interesset. Has id admodum deleniti, eu sumo iisque noluisse ius, vix facer partiendo temporibus ut. In civibus consetetur cum, quo atqui omnium periculis ne. Vim nullam nemore ut.
</textarea>
```

Unfortunately neither methods support `ellipsis` or "..."

I don't *think* there are any "non-hacky" methods of combining ellipsis and `overflow` using CSS alone unless you use [hacks](http://dev.mobify.com/blog/multiline-ellipsis-in-pure-css/) or scripts.

An example of such hacks is to use pseudo-elements (this only works if the text is justified)

```css
.sample {
  max-width: 80%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  max-height: 2.2em;
  text-align: justify;
  padding-right: .75em;
}

.sample:before {
  content: "...";
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="sample">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, cu ancillae expetendis ius, pro reque laudem facilisis in, dicta euismod qui eu. No pri graecis similique, ei vim nobis veritus argumentum, platonem torquatos vituperata eum eu. Mel purto eros legendos id, saepe laudem at qui,
  te eum semper interesset. Has id admodum deleniti, eu sumo iisque noluisse ius, vix facer partiendo temporibus ut. In civibus consetetur cum, quo atqui omnium periculis ne. Vim nullam nemore ut.
</div>
```

Comment: There's no ending "..." here?

Comment: I don't think that's possible @GustafGunér - unless you hack your way http://dev.mobify.com/blog/multiline-ellipsis-in-pure-css/ or go beyond CSS

Comment: Exactly. Not cross-browser at least. Therefore I recommend doing it in JS if the ending "..." is what's requested

Answer (score 0):

I think the only safe cross-browser solution is to use javascript for line clamping. I've used [Clamp.js](https://github.com/josephschmitt/Clamp.js/) once and I remember it being easy to use and working very well. You can read some more about the whole "line clamping issue"
 [here](https://css-tricks.com/line-clampin/).

The basic usage of Clamp.js in your case would be something like the following

```
$clamp(myText, {clamp: 2});
```

Where `myText` is the element you want to line clamp and `2` means two lines.